# How to convert image to Boolean Array in Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to store a 32 x 32 Boolean array in a 32 x 32 black and white image (either bitmap or PNG), to then be mapped to a Boolean[32][32] array with black pixels being true and white being false.

This is to store frames of animation to display on a virtual 32 x 32 display. Here's what I have so far below.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.f1);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, o_stream); 
byte[] byteArray = o_stream.toByteArray();
```

What do I do with byteArray to make it a Boolean[32][32] array or am I going about this all wrong in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you just use byte 32x32 array and represent a byte value of lowest byte range as black and a byte value of highest max byte range as a white? However, this depends on the type and color model the image uses. Therefore it may not be 32x32 byte array input in the end due to this image implementation.

Answer (score 0):

While I never did anything with images (so I don't know if this is anything close to what one should do to get the black-and-white of a pic), I suppose you need a rule to decide whether a pixel is closer to black or closer to white. But I'm curious, how can a byte represent a color? Even if it's RGB, you need at least three bytes, don't you?

Comment: I concur with you since each image format has a different color model strategy with may take more than one byte to represent a color. in case of RGBA with an alpha channel is involved, it will become four bytes to represent an RGBA color.

Comment: Specifically using black and white 1 bit 32 x 32 bitmaps, or png's, ones that I'm generating.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, the pics are already black and white? In that case, conversion should be really easy, just loop through the byte[][] and go byte by byte and check if it's equal to 1 or 0 (or whatever black and white are represented by) and assign a boolean[][] to true or false based on that.

Comment: Well I tried something like that earlier but it wasn't working for some reason, now trying it out I can get 901 bytes out of it, trying to read up on PNG's I see that the first 8 are PNG header, now to see if I can figure out how these 893 bytes work themselves out. Thanks

Comment: Hm that doesn't sound like it's a 32x32 image since that itself would have 1024 bytes (assuming 1 pixel is represented by 1 byte). I think you can use David Wasser's approach, but that implies the conversion from picture to byte[][] works the way you intend it to. Maybe that's what's bugged?

Comment: `int y = 0;
for(Byte b : byteArray){
y++;
int yo = (int)b;
Log.i("i", "#" + y + " : " + Integer.toString(yo));
}` 

doing this logging with this [image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60865697/f2.bmp) using the above code gives me 901 bytes

Comment: have you tried using the byte array you get this way to generate an image? maybe you can tell what's happening from seeing the output pic that would get you?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(src!= null){
ByteArrayOutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
src.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,(OutputStream) os);
byte[] byteArray = os.toByteArray();
//Log.d("byte=",""+byteArray.length);//returns length.
//str = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);//returns string
}

where src is the bitmap....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to encode an array of Booleans into a bitmap to save storage space, why use an image? That's a lot of extra overhead. Why not just create a bitmap yourself, like this:

```
    Boolean[][] booleanArray = ... // this is your Boolean array
    int[] bits = new int[32]; // One int holds 32 bits
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            if (booleanArray[i][j]) {
                // Set bit at the corresponding position in the bits array
                bits[i] |= 1 << j;
            }
        }
    }
    // Now  you have the data in a int array which you can write to a file
    //  using DataOutputStream. The file would contain 128 bytes.

    // To recreate the Boolean[32][32] from the int array, do this:
    Boolean[][] booleanArray = new Boolean[32][32];
    int[] bits = ... // This is the data you read from the file using DataInputStream
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            if ((bits[i] & (1 << j)) != 0) {
                // Set corresponding Boolean
                booleanArray[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
```